# Make Java installed with my app

Tags: java, exe

Is there any way I can convert my .jar to .exe and add Java to my setup file

in the same way companies attach Direct x to their games ??

when I double click it window opens and setup unzip my program in selected path then setup Java if not found

i cant explain more

Comment: You'd want to bundle the JRE, basically. I've seen it done, so yes it's possible. It will increase the size of your program significantly if it's an otherwise small program. If I recall, the game Project Zomboid does this, and has separate executable binaries for each platform.

Comment: Do you want to pack the JDK with your java program so that people without the jdk can install it, or do you have a library you wrote in java that you want to include in your installer for another program?

`i cant explain more`

sorry, you're going to have to

Comment: Many tools do that, have a look at Launch4j or NSIS for instance .

Comment: @DustinRyan-Roepsch i want pack the JDK with your java program so that people without the jdk can install it

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider i dont care about size for now the main concern is that clients doesnt like instructions that is given for them about downloading JRE and bla bla bla

Comment: ok i will try that thanks guys 
can you put answer ?

Comment: I clarified in my answer recommending Excelsior JET that it creates an EXE file for your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used [Excelsior JET](http://www.excelsiorjet.com/) for a client application with 10's of thousands of Windows installs. It significantly reduces the installation size and installation time over bundling your own JRE installer. More importantly it significantly reduces application startup time over a `java -jar` startup. It does this by compiling your Java code to a native EXE file using their certified native JRE implementation. They also provide a simple installer you can use to package your app and their native JRE runtime EXEs and DLLs. I've not found any downside to using it, as long as you're willing to use a commercial product and take the time to work through its build configuration.

If you decide to bundle the JRE with your application instead of using something like JET, your users will need admin privileges to run that installer. An alternative would be to bundle a *private* JRE. No admin is required for your end users with a private JRE. You'll want to use `pack200` and `unpack200` on the JRE jar files to keep the size under control.

Comment: can you explain more about second part of your answer ?? 
what is pack200 and unpack200

Comment: Those are exe utils for efficiently compressing (pack) and uncompressing (unpack) jar files. They can make a huge reduction to the size of a bundled JRE. They are included in the JRE `bin` directory.

Comment: @KareemElsayed You chose the Install4j answer? It's definitely easier than JET, but it's not free either.

Comment: Install4j is only free for evaluation or if you're developing for a non-profit open source project. https://www.ej-technologies.com/buy/install4j/licensing.html.

Comment: @Berger suggested Launch4j and NSIS, which would both work. Launch4j is going to be the easiest IMO, and you can always fall back to NSIS if you find something you can't do with Launch4j.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you need is native packaging, which seems has been provided in NetBeans.

You can also try **Inno Setup** to deliver your Java application in native format, as well as **IzPack** to deliver an installer.

Hope that may do some help. :-P

Comment: can you tell me with inno where to put JDK ??

Comment: @KareemElsayed I used to deliver a JavaFX app in .exe with Inno Setup, turns out it will pack the JRE you selected in whole with your app's jar file. (Kind of like Blender --as you can find the entire Python runtime environment within its install directory). Check the documentation & tutorials on Inno Setup's site for more details.

Comment: Also, the user doesn't need the JDK, just the JRE. JDK is meant to be for developers only :)

Answer (score 1):

With Install4J you have the option to include your JRE or make it downloadable from the installer if missing in the system.

Comment: I used Install4j before switching to Excelsior JET. It's a very nice cross-platform Java installer platform and the private JRE bundling works well.

Answer (score -2):

You could create a bat file which runs 
    java -jar [Your Jar file]

Then have a exe call the bat file.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question of how would a user pack the installation of the JRE with their executable Jar file, just how a user who already has a JRE installed could run it